# Formik doesn't check for errors when conditionally render fields with function

Tags: reactjs, formik

In my project I use Formik and Chakra UI (if it matters). And here is how my forms are built:

```
<BaseForm
  initialValues={passportFormInitValues}
  validationSchema={AuthPassportSchema}
  onSubmit={signIn}
  btnText='sign-in'
>
  <CustomField name='passportId' text='id' type='passport' />
  <CustomField name='password' text='password' type='password' />
</BaseForm>
```

Inside BaseForm component I just wrap all children with Formik component.

And CustomField is a generic field which renders inputs of different types depending on the type prop. Inside it looks like this:

```
<Field name={name}>
  {({ field, meta }) => ( 
    <FormControl isInvalid={meta.error && meta.touched} > 
      <FormLabel> {text} </FormLabel>
  
      <InputGroup variant='base' onFocus={focusCheck} onBlur={blurCheck}>
        {type === 'passport' && (
          <Input {...field} placeholder={text} onKeyUp={checkCapsLock} />
        )}

        {type === 'password' && (
          <Input
            {...field}
            autoComplete='on'
            placeholder={text}
            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            onKeyUp={checkCapsLock}
            onChange={passwordInputHandler}
          />
        )}

        {!(type === 'password') && meta.error && meta.touched && (
          <InputRightElement>
           <SvgIcon name='warning' dir='form' />
          </InputRightElement>
        )}

        {type === 'password' && meta.error && meta.touched && !isFocus && (
          <InputRightElement>
            <SvgIcon name='warning' dir='form' />
          </InputRightElement>
        )}
      </InputGroup>

      <FormErrorMessage >
        <Text variant='error' > {meta.error} </Text>
      </FormErrorMessage>
    </FormControl>
  )}
</Field>
```

And this code works fine. If the input data does not pass the validation then I see errors. But I decided to create a function that returned a certain input based on the type argument passed to it.

```
export default function CustomField(props) {
  const { name, staticLabel, text, type, width } = props
  ...
  ...
  function inputFromType({ field }) {
    if (type === 'passport') {
      return <Input {...field} placeholder={text} onKeyUp={checkCapsLock} /> 
    }
    
    if (type === 'password') {
      return (
        <Input
          {...field}
          autoComplete='on'
          placeholder={text}
          type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
          onKeyUp={checkCapsLock}
          onChange={passwordInputHandler}
        />
      )
    }
  }
  ...
  ...
  return (
    <Field name={name}>
      {({ field, meta }) => (
        <FormControl isInvalid={meta.error && meta.touched} >
          <FormLabel> {text} </FormLabel>

        <InputGroup variant='base' onFocus={focusCheck} onBlur={blurCheck}>
          {inputFromType(field)}
```

And it also show the proper input. But when I render fields this way Formik doesn't show errors when the input data didn't pass validation. But the validation itself seems to work because wrong input data would disable submit button. It just doesn't show me what's wrong with the form data.

What causes this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass in meta as an argument in your inputFromType fucntion. function inputFromType(field, meta). Make sure you pass in both arguments in correct order when you call this function.

Comment: it helped! Thank you! But I don't understand why it works. Since I don't use meta anywhere inside my function. My IDE also tells me that meta is declared but not used. But it fixed the CustomField component anyway

Comment: By passing the field and meta variables directly to the inputFromType function, you ensure that Formik maintains the connection with the field and can properly handle validation errors and field values.